# Show values of non-selected paths in tooltip for d3 stacked area charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a d3 stacked area visualization that consists of a main chart (national) and small multiples drawn therefrom (i.e. state charts). [Here's the Plunker for the viz I'm working on](http://plnkr.co/edit/qQrAJKgDm8qTaKHYKoUm?p=preview).

The tooltip currently displays the x and y values of the selected path. What I'm trying to achieve is this: For the state charts only, I want the tooltip to display the values of the non-selected paths, as well as the value for the selected path.

I've partly managed to achieve this on an earlier version of the visualization that I'm working on. Here's [the Plunker from which I'm trying to adapt the tooltip](http://plnkr.co/edit/q6wczPtGrwq0SLI7c0Oj?p=preview). Very similar.

This is the code that I've been struggling for several days to integrate into my existing tooltip:

```
    paths.on('mousemove', function(d, i) {
            let mousePos = d3.mouse(this);
            d3.select(this).classed('hover', true);
            MouseOverChart(d, dataset, mousePos, xScale);

function MouseOverChart(d, dataset, mousePos, xScale) {
    var xPosition = (d3.event.pageX),
        yPosition = (d3.event.pageY - 28);

  let mouseX = mousePos[0];
  var invertedX = xScale.invert(mouseX),
    bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return new Date(d.x); }).left,
        idx = bisect(d.values, invertedX);

    var content = getTooltipHeader(d,idx);
    content += '<ul class="record-list" >'
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
        content += getRecordContent(dataset[i], idx);
    }
    content += '</ul>';

  showTooltip(content, xPosition, yPosition);
} 

function showTooltip(content) {

    d3.select(".tooltip")

      .html(content);
    d3.select(".tooltip");//.classed("none", false);
}

function getRecordContent(obj, pos) {
    return '<li><span class="record-label">' + obj.record + '</span><span class="record-value">' + obj.values[pos].value + '</span></li>'
} 

function getTooltipHeader(data, pos) {
    var html = '<div class="tooltip-label"><span>' + data.values[pos].x +'</span><h3>' + data.record + '</h3></div>';
    return html; 
}
```

The problems:

1. I haven't been able to get the non-selected values to display inside my existing tooltip, or even as a separate tooltip.

   2. When mousing over the state charts, the current configuration displays the selected value twice -- once in the tooltip header, and again in `<record-list>`. I've tested various `filter` conditions to suppress the value and its label from being displayed in `<record-list>` if it already appears in `<tooltip-header>`, but I haven't been successful.

[Here, again, is the Plunker for the viz I'm working on](http://plnkr.co/edit/qQrAJKgDm8qTaKHYKoUm?p=preview). 
[And here's the Plunker from which I'm adapting the tooltip](http://plnkr.co/edit/q6wczPtGrwq0SLI7c0Oj?p=preview)

Thanks in advance for any help you're able to offer.

**Edit, 29 November 2017:**

I've made a little progress; the tooltip does not appear — albeit without any values — when mousing over the dates of 29 January 2009 and 1 March 2009, but not on any other dates:
[image: tooltip not working]

I'm continuing to work on this, but I'm definitely stuck, and would still appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those still following along at home, I managed to solve this.

Here's an updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NfMeTpXzXGTxgNFKPFJe?p=preview

[image]

The relevant code:

```
    paths.on('mousemove', function(d, i) {
            let mousePos = d3.mouse(this);
            d3.select(this).classed('hover', true);
            MouseOverChart(d, dataset, mousePos, xScale);


function MouseOverChart(d, dataset, mousePos, xScale) {
    //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
    var xPosition = (d3.event.pageX),
            yPosition = (d3.event.pageY - 28);

  let mouseX = mousePos[0];// + 1;
  var invertedX = xScale.invert(mouseX),
    bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return new Date(d.x); }).left,
        idx = bisect(d.values, invertedX);

      function getMonth(date) {
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        return month < 10 ? '0' + month : '' + month; // ('' + month) for string result
      }

      invertedX = ("" + (invertedX.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + invertedX.getFullYear();
      var selected = (d.values);

      for (var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++) {
        dates[k] = selected[k].x
        dates[k] = ("" + (dates[k].getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + dates[k].getFullYear();
      } 

      idx = dates.indexOf(invertedX);

    var content = getTooltipHeader(d,idx);

    content += '<ul class="record-list" >'
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
        content += getRecordContent(dataset[i], idx);

    }
    content += '</ul>';

  showTooltip(content, xPosition, yPosition);
} //closes MouseOverChart function

function getTooltipHeader(data, pos) {
  var hoverdate = data.values[pos].x;
  var invertedxmo = data.values[pos].x;
  var invertedxyr = data.values[pos].x;  

      function getMonth(date) {
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        return month < 10 ? '0' + month : '' + month; // ('' + month) for string result
      }

      hoverdate = ("" + (hoverdate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + hoverdate.getFullYear();
      var selected = (d.values);

      for (var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++) {
        dates[k] = selected[k].x
        dates[k] = ("" + (dates[k].getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + dates[k].getFullYear();
      } 
      invertedxmo = ("" + (invertedxmo.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) ;
      var selectedmo = (d.values);

      for (var m = 0; k < selectedmo.length; k++) {
        dates[m] = selectedmo[m].x
        dates[m] = ("" + (dates[m].getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) ;
      }       
      invertedxyr = invertedxyr.getFullYear();

      var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
      ];

    var html = '<div class="tooltip-label"><span>' + monthNames[invertedxmo-1] + " " + invertedxyr + '</span><h3>' + " "  + data.state + '<br/>' +  data.record.toLowerCase() + " " + numFormat(data.values[pos].y) + '</h3></div>';
    return html; 
} //closes getTooltipHeader function

function getRecordContent(obj, pos) {
    return '<li><span class="record-label">' + obj.record + '</span><span class="record-value">' + numFormat(obj.values[pos].y) + '</span></li>'    
} //closes getRecordContent function
```

and

```
function showTooltip(content, xPosition, yPosition) {
      tt.html('<span class="record">' + d.state + "</span>" + '<br/>' + '<br/>' + '<span class="dataNum">' +  '</span>' + " " + d.record.toLowerCase() )
         .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 12 + 'px')
        .style('visibility', 'visible')
        .html(content);
}
```

This code could use some cleanup, but it's functional.

I'm still looking for a way of eliminating the redundant presentation of the selected value. Currently, if you hover over an area, the values of the selected path (at the bisection of a given month) appear both in the tooltip's `header` div and in its `record-list` div.

Does anyone has a suggestion for a way of implementing, perhaps, a filter function that removes the selected value from `record-list` — or alternatively, a way of introducing a condition for `record-list` such that it displays the selected value in bold font (thereby making clear that it is the "selected" one, and obviating the same value to appear again in the header)?